# Tweak to existing AMPscript to add a further clause

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm currently using the following AMPscript which doesn't how the Variable Scholarship Title and Amount if those fields are empty.  This works as expected (as it was provided by some kind souls on this site!).

```
Scholarship Title: %%Application Scholarship Title%%  
Scholarship Amount: $%%=FormatNumber(AttributeValue("Application Scholarship Amount"),"#,###")=%% %%[
  SET @rows = LookupRows("Contact_Salesforce","Id", _subscriberkey)
  SET @row = row(@rows,1)
  SET @Variable_Scholarship_Name__c = 
  field(@row,"Variable_Scholarship_Name__c")
  SET @Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c = 
  field(@row,"Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c")
  IF NOT EMPTY(@Variable_Scholarship_Name__c) THEN
  ]%%
Scholarship Title: %%=v(@Variable_Scholarship_Name__c)=%%
Scholarship Amount: 
  $%%=v(FormatNumber(@Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c,"#,###"))=%%
  %%[ENDIF]%%
```

I now need to expand on this so that it displays the following:

1. If Application Scholarship Title, Application Scholarship Amount, Variable_Scholarship_Name__c & Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c are null - show nothing
2. If **Application Scholarship Title & Application Scholarship Amount** are populated but Variable_Scholarship_Name__c & Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c are null then show only **Application Scholarship Title & Application Scholarship**.
3. If **Variable_Scholarship_Name__c & Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c** are populated but Application Scholarship Title & Application Scholarship Amount are null then show only **Variable_Scholarship_Name__c & Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c**.

Thank you!

Comment: what have you tried? im not seeing any problems in your code

Comment: The above code only handles the second example, not the first or third.  I plain don't know how to add further clauses within the AMPscript I have unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the outputs only to be displayed if values are present, you can do the following:

```
%%[

Set @Application_Scholarship_Title = AttributeValue("Application Scholarship Title")
Set @Application_Scholarship_Amount = AttributeValue("Application Scholarship Amount")

SET @rows = LookupRows("Contact_Salesforce","Id", _subscriberkey)
SET @row = row(@rows,1)

SET @Variable_Scholarship_Name__c = field(@row,"Variable_Scholarship_Name__c",0)
SET @Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c = field(@row,"Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c",0)

]%%

%%[IF NOT EMPTY(@Application_Scholarship_Title) THEN]%%
  Scholarship Title: %%=v(@Application_Scholarship_Title)=%%<br>
%%[ENDIF]%%
%%[IF NOT EMPTY(@Application_Scholarship_Amount) THEN]%%
  Scholarship Amount: $%%=v(FormatNumber(@Application_Scholarship_Amount,"#,###"))=%%<br>
%%[ENDIF]%%
%%[IF NOT EMPTY(@Variable_Scholarship_Name__c) THEN]%%
  Scholarship Title: %%=v(@Variable_Scholarship_Name__c)=%%<br>
%%[ENDIF]%%
%%[IF NOT EMPTY(@Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c) THEN]%%
  Scholarship Amount: $%%=v(FormatNumber(@Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c,"#,###"))=%%<br>
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

if you want it solely on what you have in your above (what happens if all 4 have values? Or you have one application and 2 variable, etc?), see below conditional to meet your specific ask:

```
%%[IF (NOT EMPTY(@Application_Scholarship_Title) AND NOT EMPTY(@Application_Scholarship_Amount)) AND (EMPTY(@Variable_Scholarship_Name__c) AND EMPTY(@Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c)) THEN]%%
  Scholarship Title: %%=v(@Application_Scholarship_Title)=%%<br>
  Scholarship Amount: $%%=v(FormatNumber(@Application_Scholarship_Amount,"#,###"))=%%<br>
%%[ELSEIF (NOT EMPTY(@Variable_Scholarship_Name__c) AND NOT EMPTY(@Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c)) AND (EMPTY(@Application_Scholarship_Title) AND EMPTY(@Application_Scholarship_Amount)) THEN]%%
  Scholarship Title: %%=v(@Variable_Scholarship_Name__c)=%%<br>
  Scholarship Amount: $%%=v(FormatNumber(@Variable_Scholarship_Amount__c,"#,###"))=%%<br>
%%[ELSE]%%
  <!-- No Results -->
%%[ENDIF]%%
```